# ST_Intersects with ST_collect

Tags: postgis, postgresql

We found that `ST_intersects (ST_collect(<collection of polygons>), <polygonK>)` is slower than

```
 ST_intersects (<polygon1 from collection>, <polygonK>)
 union
 ST_intersects (<polygon2 from collection>, <polygonK>)
 union
 ST_intersects (<polygon3 from collection>, <polygonK>)
   .
   .
   .
union
 ST_intersects (<polygonN from collection>, <polygonK>)
```

any reason why would that be the case. It seems like PostGIS could have done this optimization internally in `ST_interset`?

Comment: My guess is that `(ST_collect(<collection of polygons>)` has no entry in the spatial index while the native polygons have.

Comment: We really need to see the `explain` output to be able to say

Comment: The combined bounding box of a collection of polygons is likely to include a vast number of false hits; e.g. a bounding box enclosing a collection of the areal geometry of New York and the areal geometry of San Francisco would return an index hit for all areal geometries of basically all cities in the US - with each one of them then having to undergo an actual, costly intersection check. The index lookup for both cities individually would return only those in the direct vicinity each, dramatically reducing the amount of intersection checks.

Comment: @geozelot we are not using ST_union to make it combined bounding box, unless I am not understanding difference between ST_collect vs ST_union? If I understand it correctly, ST_collect doesn't make it a single combined polygon.

Comment: `ST_Collect` does no geometric component manipulation like `ST_Union`, yet it creates a single geometric object of (the PostGIS) type `GEOMETRY`, having the least possible dimension to hold all geometries it collects (i.e. a `MULTI` geometry or `GEOMETRY COLLECTION`) - this single `GEOMETRY` type then inherently has a single *bounding box* that encloses all geometry parts it holds.

Comment: E.g. run `SELECT ST_Envelope(ST_Collect(geom)) ...` to get a `POLYGON` geometry representing the bounding box for inspection - this extent is what is used to find bounding box intersections.

Answer (score 4):

The performance difference may be due to the way spatial indexes are utilized in the two approaches. When using ST_Intersects(ST_Collect(), ), the spatial index may not be fully utilized because the combined geometry may not effectively leverage the index structure. This can result in slower performance as a full scan of the combined geometry may be required.

On the other hand, the union of individual ST_Intersects calls takes advantage of the spatial index efficiently for each individual operation. By performing the operations separately and then merging the results, the query planner can optimize the process more effectively.

In summary, the second approach with the union of individual ST_Intersects calls is generally more efficient when dealing with a large collection of polygons.